# How to download the latest artifact from artifactory repository using teamcity via artifactory plugin

Tags: download, teamcity, artifactory, artifacts, team-city-10.0

I'm trying to download the latest version of an artifact from JFROG Artifactory repository present in a common folder using the artifactory plugin in Teamcity.

Following is how the artifcatory repository looks like

```
My_Repo/my_tool

1.0/too1.zip
2.0/tool.zip
3.0/tool.zip
4.0/tool.zip
5.0/tool.zip
```

I tried using the following syntax in the artifactory plugin of teamcity but neither of them work in downloading the latest artifact.

Under "Custom build dependencies:"

```
My_Repo:my_tool/#LATEST
My_Repo:my_tool/LATEST
```

Currently I should download version 5.0 of the tool but if there is a new version 6.0, that should get automatically downloaded as soon as it is available and I do not want to hard-code the version number in my Teamicty jobs.

Can any of the experienced users of teamcity shed some light on how to achieve this.